# How to fscanf only the elements that we want?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to do fscanf on a .txt file, here's how it looks

```
7  6
[1,2]="english"
[1,4]="linear"
[2,4]="calculus"
[3,1]="pe"
[3,3]="Programming"
```

I want to take only the 2 numbers in the brackets, the first is day, and the second is session, and I also want to take the string subject

Here's the whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *inputFile, *outputFile;
    
    int day;
    int session;
    char subject[15];
    
    inputFile = fopen("Schedule.txt", "r");
        if (inputFile == NULL) {
            puts("File Schedule.txt Open Error.");
        }
    
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d %s", &day, &session, subject);
    
    printf("%d", day);
    
    fclose(inputFile);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Apparently the fscanf does not work the way i want it to.

The expected output is storing the numbers to the variables I have assigned

What actually happened is it only printed out '7'

Comment: What else did you expect it to print?  `printf("%d", day);` is quite explicit about what you print

Comment: You should check the return value of `fscanf`. It will tell you the number of items that were converted. BTW: instead of `puts` you might want to use `perror` for error messages and make sure you don't call `fscanf` with a NULL pointer.

Comment: The magic numbers 7 and 6 seems to mean something special, you probably need to learn what.

Comment: @Theodore Maximus, Be prepared that the _subject_ may have spaces in it.

Comment: Interesting [dig](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+dig+at+someone): `"Programming"` capitalized, yet `"english"` and others not capitalized.  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to take only the 2 numbers in the brackets, the first is day, and the second is session, and I also want to take the string subject

(I leave OP to handle first line `"7  6\n"`.)

Drop all `fscanf()` calls.  Use `fgets()` to read a *line* and then parse.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inputFile)) {
  // Parse input like <[1,2]="english"\n>
  int day;
  int session;
  char subject[15];
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, " [%d ,%d ] = \"%14[^\"]\" %n",
    &day, &session, subject, &n);
  bool Success = n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0';
  ...
```

Scan the string.  If  entirely successful, `n` will be non-zero and `buf[n]` will pointer to the string's end.

`" "` Consume optional white spaces.
`"["` Consume a `[`.
`"%d"` Consume optional spaces and then numeric text for an `int`.
`","` Consume a `,`.
`"]"` Consume a `]`.
`"\""` Consume a double quote mark.
`"%14[^\"]"` Consume 1 to up to 14 non-double quote characters and form a *string*.
`"%n"` Save the offset of the scan as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach reading line by line and using `sscanf`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINEBUFSIZE 500

int main(){
    FILE *inputFile;
    
    char line[LINEBUFSIZE];
    
    inputFile = fopen("Schedule.txt", "r");
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        puts("File Schedule.txt Open Error.");
    }

    while (fgets(line, LINEBUFSIZE, inputFile)) {
        int day;
        int session;
        char subject[15];
        int r;
        // %14s because char subject[15] (14 char + null)
        r = sscanf(line, "[%d,%d]=%14s", &day, &session, subject);
        if (r != 3)
            // Could not read 3 elements
            continue;
        printf("%d %d %s\n", day, session, subject);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: But neither your code nor the OP's do anything about handling the first line of the input (which is formatted differently).

Comment: Yeah, it just skips lines that sscanf can't read 3 elements. I will edit the code if OP says something about those cases

Comment: You might also like to add some explanation as to *how* the format string in your `sscanf` call works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for clarification the 7 6 is the format given by my teacher, and I cannot do anything about it haha. This works fine, thank you very much